# 1.9 - No Payment Methods showing up

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

I upgraded an extension for points which can be used at checkout, and it seemingly broke my OPC. No payment methods are displayed at all.

I'm not sure what happened, but it caused my PayPal settings to force me to input API credentials, when it didn't before. It also forced me to use Express with Standard. I looked this up and changed it back manually via `core_config_data`.

I uninstalled the extension, however they still aren't appearing.

[image]

I'm looking for any suggestions on what to do. I did not take a backup before upgrading this extension. Yeah, I know, I've learned my lesson.

A backup of the entire app folder did nothing.

Comment: Enable Cash on delivery for testing. I think there is misconfiguration of payment methods. If cash on delivery works then you need to recheck the settings of payment methods properly.

Comment: I had initially enabled all of the other payments to see if it was just PayPal, but no payments were showing up (I then disabled them all again).  I resolved this issue, unfortunately I'm not 100% sure how. After uploading my last back up, and clearing the cache in every way I know how (command line, admin panel, cdn, physically deleting all cache folders), it eventually started working.  The strange part was that all of the payment methods were re-enabled (not by me). So, I'm unsure if it was the backup, or if the cache just wasn't cleared completely after I initially disabled the extension.